# reconstruct the binary tree with two lists after preorder and inorder

Tags: haskell

--Two lists are given, one sorted by preorder, the other sorted by inorder. And the two lists are from the same binary tree. With the two lists the binary tree is --reconstructed.

-- I haven't found the function "rank" online. My professor told us that the function "rank" can output the position of one element in a list.

The error occured in the following line where the function "rank" were used.

So I have two questions.

1. How ist the function "rank"?
2. Is the expression  "reconstruct :: [Int]->IntTree" correct ? I am not sure.

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

data IntTree = Empty | Branch IntTree Int IntTree deriving (Show, Eq)

reconstruct :: [Int]->IntTree
--  Pattern matching 
reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take((rank x y) xs) take ((rank x y) y)) x x (reconstruct drop ((rank x y)+1 xs) drop ((rank x y)+1 y))
```

after correction

```
import Data.List


main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

data IntTree = Empty | Branch IntTree Int IntTree deriving (Show, Eq)

--Two lists are given, one sorted by preorder, the other sorted by inorder. 
-- And the two lists are from the same binary tree. With the two lists the binary tree is reconstructed.

reconstruct :: [Int]->[Int]->IntTree
--  Pattern matching 
reconstruct [] [] = Empty
reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))
    where p = span (x/=) y 

reconstruct _ _ = error "incomplete pattern"
```

the error

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:32: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> IntTree'
                  with actual type `IntTree'
    * The function `reconstruct' is applied to three arguments,
      but its type `[Int] -> [Int] -> IntTree' has only two
      In the first argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))'
      In the expression:
        Branch
          (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))
          x
          (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:44: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int]'
                  with actual type `Int -> [a0] -> [a0]'
    * Probable cause: `take' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of `reconstruct', namely `take'
      In the first argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))'
      In the expression:
        Branch
          (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))
          x
          (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                            ^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:50: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> [Int]'
                  with actual type `Int'
    * The function `length' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `[Int] -> Int' has only one
      In the second argument of `reconstruct', namely
        `(length (fst p) xs)'
      In the first argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))'
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:81: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> IntTree'
                  with actual type `IntTree'
    * The function `reconstruct' is applied to three arguments,
      but its type `[Int] -> [Int] -> IntTree' has only two
      In the third argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))'
      In the expression:
        Branch
          (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))
          x
          (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:93: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int]'
                  with actual type `Int -> [a1] -> [a1]'
    * Probable cause: `drop' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of `reconstruct', namely `drop'
      In the third argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))'
      In the expression:
        Branch
          (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))
          x
          (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                                                                             ^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1.hs:15:99: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> [Int]'
                  with actual type `Int'
    * The function `length' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `[Int] -> Int' has only one
      In the second argument of `reconstruct', namely
        `(length (fst p) xs)'
      In the third argument of `Branch', namely
        `(reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))'
   |
15 | reconstruct (x:xs) y = Branch (reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p)) x (reconstruct drop (length (fst p) xs) (snd p))

   |                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Comment: I have no idea what `rank` is - it's certainly not a standard Haskell function. You should ask your professor.

Comment: Type signature for `reconstruct` doesn't match the number of arguments provided. If the input is two lists, then perhaps `reconstruct :: [Int] -> [Int] -> IntTree`. I think you have function binding precedence wrong in your head - `f a (b) c = f a b c` not `f (a b) c` (note `f (a) = f a`, `f (a b) /= f a b`). From the description, `rank` is just standard Haskell `find`. You might benefit from using `splitAt` rather than `drop`, `take`.

Answer (score 1):

```
reconstruct :: [Int] -> [Int] -> IntTree
reconstruct [] [] = Empty
reconstruct (x:xs) y = let (l,_:r) = span (x /=) y
                           (l',r') = splitAt (length l) xs
                       in Branch (reconstruct l' l) x (reconstruct r' r)
reconstruct _ _ = error "incomplete pattern"
```

This seemed to work on the single testcase I tried, and is pretty much what you intended to write (I think). It runs into issues if nodes can have left-descendants with equal contents to themselves (?). I think it might traverse `l` twice (due to `length`), you could solve this with a `zip`and some extra logic if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to understand it

Comment: @A Tayler `ghci> span (/=4) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
([1,2,3],[4,5,6,7])` I have found the example of the function "span". But I don't see what "(l,_:r)" and ""(l,_:r)"" mean? Can I use the fst und sec to get the lists?

Comment: `(l, _:r)` binds a tuple, the second element of which is a non-empty list. `l` becomes the first element, `r` becomes the `tail` of the second element. You could write `p = span ...` `l = fst p` `r = tail . snd $ p` but as you can see, it's much more verbose. `_` says we're ignoring the `head` of the list in the right-half of the tuple - technically because we "know" it's `x`, this replicates the `+1` in your code that drops the `x`.

Comment: I am new in Haskell bro

Comment: Try writing `ghci > (l,_:r) = span (/=4) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` then examining the values of `l`,`r`.

Comment: @  A Tayler I have tried...but my professor don't allow us to use the knowledge that we haven't lerned. And I have correted the program but one error exists still .... The corrected program is in the above....

Comment: @LeonhardFelix as I said in an earlier comment, you have misunderstood how function application precedence works. You wrote `f a (b c d) e` instead of `f (a (b c) d) e`, they are completely different (here `f` is `reconstruct`, `a` is `take`/`drop`, `b` is `length`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> The function `reconstruct' is applied to three arguments, but its type `[Int] -> [Int] -> IntTree' has only two

```
(reconstruct take (length (fst p) xs) (fst p))
```

You apply the `reconstruct` functions to 3 arguments, as stated in the error message: `take`, `(length (fst p) xs)` and `(fst p)`.

Similar error is with length application: you pass 2 arguments to it.

Maybe you meant to pass `FUNCTION(ARGUMENT)` as single argumetn to next function. It does not work like this, it would be considered as 2 arguments: `FUNCTION` and `(ARGUMENT)`. Instead you should use `(FUNCTION ARGUMENT)`, or `(FUNCTION (ARGUMENT))` if the ARGUMENT is complex.

Also, you should not group arguments to functions separately from the function: `take (length ... LIST)`. This is considered as single argument `(length ... LIST)`. They should be on same bracket level with the function.

So your first reconstruct call would rather look like:

```
(reconstruct (take (length (fst p)) xs) (fst p))
```

And probably the rest of the expression have similar issues